# Gatsby <div> appears only on refresh

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I've injected a script in the  of my website using the Netlify snippet injection feature and access it with using a div

```
<div data-mantis-zone="captain-jack"></div>
```

When I navigate from home to the blog post where the `<div>` is located, it loads only when I refresh the page.

Is there a way I force Gatsby to refresh the div when I'm coming from a different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not intended to do so and it's a weird behavior, but you can use a `useEffect` + `useState` hooks.

```
const YourPage = ()=>{
  const [emptyState, setEmptyState]=useState("");

  useEffect(()=>{
    setEmptyState(" ");
   
  }, [])

return <div>
    <div data-mantis-zone={`captain-jack ${emptyState}`}></div>
</div>

}
```

This snippet will force the rehydration of the `<div>` once the `useEffect` is triggered (when the DOM tree is loaded). Since the `<div>` holds a state which changes because of the `useEffect` hook.

Overall, is a dirty approach, you should debug why is not loading that script in Netlify and find a better solution.